# image processing to improve tesseract OCR

Tags: tesseract

I've been using tesseract to convert documents into text. The quality of the documents ranges wildly, and I'm looking for tips on what sort of image processing might improve the results. I've noticed that text that is highly pixellated - for example that generated by fax machines - is especially difficult for tesseract to process - presumably all those jagged edges to the characters confound the shape-recognition algorithms.

What sort of image processing techniques would improve the accuracy? I've been using a Gaussian blur to smooth out the pixellated images and seen some small improvement, but I'm hoping that there is a more specific technique that would yield better results. Say a filter that was tuned to black and white images, which would smooth out irregular edges, followed by a filter which would increase the contrast to make the characters more distinct.

Any general tips for someone who is a novice at image processing?

Comment: Did you get any success with this, I see major issues with Tesseract at the same time some of the commercial libraries do well on same image. I too tried with Gaussian blur or even medianBlur to smoothen the edges but still it does not give me success beyond say 20-30%.

Comment: Sir, what you did for improvement, i am also looking for answer of this question?